# Installing Telegram CLI on Centos 6

Tags: centos, telegram

I followed installation instructions from [github](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) up till `./configure` command, but failed on make command. Error as below:

```
root@webserver [~/tg]# make
make: *** No rule to make target `tgl/scheme.tl', needed by `auto/scheme.tl'.  Stop.
```

Here is the result after ./configure

```
root@webserver [~/tg]# ./configure
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for sqrt in -lm... yes
checking for library containing clock_gettime... -lrt
checking for library containing backtrace... none required
checking for event_base_new in -levent... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking event2/event.h usability... no
checking event2/event.h presence... no
checking for event2/event.h... no
checking event.h usability... yes
checking event.h presence... yes
checking for event.h... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking whether compiling and linking against OpenSSL works... yes
checking if zlib is wanted... yes
checking for inflateEnd in -lz... yes
checking zlib.h usability... yes
checking zlib.h presence... yes
checking for zlib.h... yes
checking for rl_save_prompt in -lreadline... yes
checking for libconfig... enabled
checking for config_init in -lconfig... yes
checking for liblua... enabled
checking for lua... /usr/bin/lua
checking if /usr/bin/lua is a Lua interpreter... yes
checking for lua version... 5.1
checking for lua platform... unknown
checking for lua script directory... ${prefix}/share/lua/5.1
checking for lua module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/lua/5.1
checking if LUA_VERSION is defined... yes
checking lua.h usability... yes
checking lua.h presence... yes
checking for lua.h... yes
checking lualib.h usability... yes
checking lualib.h presence... yes
checking for lualib.h... yes
checking lauxlib.h usability... yes
checking lauxlib.h presence... yes
checking for lauxlib.h... yes
checking luaconf.h usability... yes
checking luaconf.h presence... yes
checking for luaconf.h... yes
checking for Lua header version... 5.1
checking if Lua header version matches 5.1... yes
checking if LUA_VERSION is defined... yes
checking for library containing exp... none required
checking for library containing dlopen... -ldl
checking for library containing lua_load... -llua-5.1
checking for python... enabled
checking for python build information...
checking for python3.5... no
checking for python3.4... no
checking for python3.3... no
checking for python3.2... no
checking for python3.1... no
checking for python3... no
checking for python2.7... no
checking for python2.6... python2.6
checking for main in -lpython2.6... yes
 results of the Python check:
  Binary:      python2.6
  Library:     python2.6
  Include Dir: /usr/include/python2.6
checking for libjansson... enabled
checking for json_array_set_new in -ljansson... yes
checking progname... default
checking execinfo.h usability... yes
checking execinfo.h presence... yes
checking for execinfo.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking malloc.h usability... yes
checking malloc.h presence... yes
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking netdb.h usability... yes
checking netdb.h presence... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking arpa/inet.h usability... yes
checking arpa/inet.h presence... yes
checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
checking mach/mach.h usability... no
checking mach/mach.h presence... no
checking for mach/mach.h... no
checking netinet/in.h usability... yes
checking netinet/in.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking sys/file.h usability... yes 
checking sys/file.h presence... yes
checking for sys/file.h... yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking termios.h usability... yes
checking termios.h presence... yes
checking for termios.h... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for uid_t in sys/types.h... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... no
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible realloc... no
checking for alarm... yes
checking for endpwent... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for mkdir... yes
checking for select... yes
checking for socket... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strndup... yes
checking for uname... yes
checking for __builtin_bswap32... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
```

Here's the content of telegram folder

```
root@webserver [~/tg]# ls
./              dep/         lua-tg.h                README.es
../             event-old.h  m4_ax_check_openssl.m4  README-LUA
auto/           gentoo/      m4_ax_check_zlib.m4     README.md
ax_lua.m4       .git/        m4-ax_gcc_builtin.m4    README-PY.md
ax_python.m4    .gitignore   main.c                  rpm/
bin/            .gitmodules  Makefile                server.pub
bootstrap*      interface.c  Makefile.in             start-telegram-daemon*
CHANGELOG       interface.h  Makefile.tgl            telegram-cli-  cygwin.patch
config.h        json-tg.c    Makefile.tl-parser      telegram-cli.spec
config.h.in     json-tg.h    mime.types@             telegram-daemon*
config.log      libs/        objs/                   telegram.h
config.sample   LICENSE      python-tg.c             test.lua
config.status*  LICENSE.h    python-tg.h             tgl/
configure*      loop.c       python-types.c          tg-server.pub
configure.ac    loop.h       python-types.h          tg-test.py
debian/         lua-tg.c     README-Cygwin.md*       .travis.yml
```

bin & tgl folder are empty by the way. Can anyone please help how to install this? I'm not familiar with centos command

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you did a recursive git clone (`git clone --recursive`)?

This issue is happening because the tgl folder is empty.